# GitHub v3 API - how do I create the initial commit in a repository?

Tags: api, github, repository, github-api

I'm using the v3 API and managed to list repos/trees/branches, access file contents, and create blobs/trees/commits. I'm now trying to create a new repo, and managed to do it with "POST user/repos"

But when I try to create blobs/trees/commits/references in this new repo I get the same error message. (409) "Git Repository is empty.". Obviously I can go and init the repository myself through the git command line, but would rather like if my application did it for me.

Is there a way to do that? What's the first thing I need to do through the API after I create an empty repository?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like they don't support it yet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670604/github-v3-api-how-to-create-initial-commit-for-my-shiny-new-repository

Answer (score 3):

Since 2012, it is now possible to auto initialize a repository after creation, according to [this blog post](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-9-28-auto-init-for-repositories/) published on the GitHub blog:

> Today we’ve made it easier to add commits to a repository via the GitHub API. Until now, you could create a repository, but you would need to initialize it locally via your Git client before adding any commits via the API.
>
> Now you can optionally init a repository when it’s created by sending true for the auto_init parameter:
>
> ```
> curl -i -u pengwynn \
>      -d '{"name": "create-repo-test", "auto_init": true}' \
>      https://api.github.com/user/repos
> ```
>
> The resulting repository will have a README stub and an initial commit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an **empty** initial commit (i.e. one without any file) you can do the following:

1. Create the repository using the `auto_init` option as in Jai Pandya's answer; *or*, if the repository already exists, use [the create file endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) to create a dummy file - this will create the branch:

```
PUT https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/contents/dummy

{
  "branch": "master",
  "message": "Create a dummy file for the sake of creating a branch",
  "content": "ZHVtbXk="
}
```

This will give you a bunch of data including a commit SHA, but you can discard all of it since we are about to obliterate that commit.

2. Use [the create commit endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit) to create a commit that points to [the empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/is-gits-semi-secret-empty-tree-object-reliable-and-why-is-there-not-a-symbolic):

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/git/commits

{
  "message": "Initial commit",
  "tree": "4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904"
}
```

This time you need to take note of the returned commit SHA.

3. Use [the update reference endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference) to make the branch point to the commit you just created (notice the Use Of The Force<sup>TM</sup>):

```
PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/git/refs/heads/master

{
    "sha": "<the SHA of the commit>",
    "force": true
}
```

4. Done! Your repository has now one branch, one commit and zero files.

Comment: Interesting. +1. I documented the empty tree in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309

Answer (score 1):

Update May 2013: Note that the [repository content API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) now authorize [adding files](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file).

See "[File CRUD and repository statistics now available in the API](https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api)".

---

Original answer (May 2012)

Since it doesn't seems to be supported yet ("[GitHub v3 API: How to create initial commit for my shiny new repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670604/github-v3-api-how-to-create-initial-commit-for-my-shiny-new-repository)", as [aclark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185820/aclark) comments), you can start by pushing an **initial *empty* commit**

```
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial commit'
git push origin master
```

That can be a good practice to [initialize one's repository](http://kevin.deldycke.com/2010/05/initialize-git-repositories/) anyway.
And it is illustrated in "[git's semi-secret empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/gits-semi-secret-empty-tree/9766506#9766506)".

Comment: thanks. Really weird that the API would support creating repos, but not initing them.

Answer (score 1):

2023 January: The 2. step of [Konamiman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53471834/21081453) did not work for me, unless I deleted the dummy file with the contents api:

```
DELETE https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/contents/dummy

{
  "branch": "master",
  "message": "Delete dummy file",
  "sha": "e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391"
}
```

(This `sha` is for the empty content `""`.)

After deleting the dummy file somehow `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` becomes assignable to a new commit.

It looks like over time this changed. It feels bad to rely on undocumented API behavior. :(